# Accessing a parents methods and variables correctly?

Tags: java, reference

So this may be a very simple question that I'm overthinking but if I do something like the following:

```
class A{
    public String test_string = "before (default)";
    public A(){
        B b = new B(this);
    }
    public void testA(){
        this.test_string = "after (new)";
    }
}
```

where B is:

```
class B{
    private A parent;
    public B(A mParent){
        parent = mParent;
    }
    private void testB(){
        System.out.println(parent.test_string);
    }
}
```

Would that allow me to still access the same instance of `A` (all of its public fields and methods)? If I called `A.testA()` from another class somewhere else on that specific instance of `A`, would the `B` that was constructed in that `A`'s constructor's `testB` function return the `"after (new)"` string? Or would that be a copy of `A` because doesn't java assign by value, not reference? Is there a better way of doing this? Am I just over complicating the issue?

I wasn't sure what to search for so I couldn't find other questions that answered my question.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Anything in particular precluding you from opening up a new code file and just.. trying it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is the same instance. It works like shown in this image:

[image]

So, calling a method over b.parent.foo, it is called over the same instance passed in the constructor.

Comment: Thanks! The image is helpful, too.

Answer (score 2):

It is breaking encapsulation to have public fields in a class and access them. Please wrap them in accessors if you must have them.

Besides, if you stick by the "tell don't ask" rule, then actually your code would be:

```
private void testB(){
    parent.printTestString();
}
```

and in A you'd have

```
public void printTestString(){
    System.out.println(test_string);
}
```

In answer to your question

"Would that allow me to still access the same instance of A (all of its public fields and methods)? If I called A.testA() from another class somewhere else on that specific instance of A"

Yes it would if it was the same instance.

"would the B that was constructed in that A's constructor's testB function return the "after (new)" string?"

Yes it would, the member field would be pointed to a new string reference so any usage of that instance of A would get the same value (threadsafety notwithstanding)